# Why do my postgresql commands get killed instantly?

Tags: postgresql, zsh

I am just learning databases now and installed postgresql via hombrew.

All my postgresql commands get killed.

```
    postgres -v
[1]    33097 killed     postgres -v

    psql postgres
[1]    31729 killed     psql postgres
```

I can start the server with `brew services start postgresql`
but anything else gets the same killed message. I cannot even create a server with `createdb myDB`

All other commands seem to be working without any problems.

I am using Z shell on macOS

Comment: If you use a different shell, does it work then?

Comment: There was a problem with code signing on some Macs when JIT was enabled using some package managers.  Look in the system log files (something like /var/log/syslog) to see if the system admits to killing it.

Comment: It gets still killed in a different shell

Comment: com.apple.mdworker.shared.10000000-0100-0000-0000-000000000000[10887]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by mds[104]

Comment: I could only find this in the system log file

Comment: That log entry doesn't see to be relevant.  What about sibling log files?  I'm not a mac user, maybe it was kern.log or something like that.

Comment: kernel shoudtown log is practically empty.

Comment: For now, I installed postgresql using postgresql.app and it is working. Still not sure why the homebrew one gets killed